# Pass data from one function to another function within same Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, components

I am having 2 functions within the same angular component (Am using angular4). I have initialized a string variable as null globally and then I have assigned value to that variable in one function. Now I have to get the value in my second function. But its still taking the initial value "NULL". Can someone help me in fixing this ?

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
etag: string = null;

constructor() {}
ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
}

getData(): void {
  this.etag = "t498dgs8";
}

printData(): void {
 console.log(this.etag);
}
}
```

Comment: where are you calling `printData()` function from ?

Comment: As Faisal said, if the function is called when you pressed a button or anything else it should work. If you want more help. Explain more the context

Comment: you are Correct PierBJX. Its "onclick" function from HTML page. GetData() function is initialized automatically and onclick functionality (printData() function) have to print the value from GetData().

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling

**getData**() method first and after 
**printData**() it can't go wrong.

But, if **getData**() method actually an **async** method, meaning it's **subscribe** or **promise** this will give null because when the time you are calling **printData**(), **getData**() method's async part is not completed.

For example, 
If **getData**() method call an API it will take some time to assign the value **etag**.

Hope this will help.

Comment: If I try to print the etag value from inside the getData() function, its working cool. But its not from printData() function.

Comment: Can u tell me what is the place you call **printData()** function?

I reproduce this, but I'm not getting **NULL** unless I call **printData()** function from the **constructor**.

Comment: printData() function is called from HTML page (on-click) event.